# www-data user not able to write to fifo, chmodded 777

Tags: php, apache, permissions, system, chmod

I wrote a little PHP script that I'd like to call from Apache.  I'm intending to use this to control pianobar.

If I execute the script directly from a root terminal, it works just fine, but if I try to run the script through the web server, nothing.

The fifo I created is at /home/dave/.config/pianobar/piano and the relevant lines in the PHP script look like this...

```
<?php
system("echo -n 'p' > /home/dave/.config/pianobar/piano"); //'p' pauses pianobar.

echo system('whoami');
?>
```

If I execute this script in a browser through Apache, it echoes 'www-data www-data' which tells me that safe mode is disabled and the `system()` command is working, but pianobar keeps playing.  If I run this from a root terminal, it echoes back 'root' and pianobar pauses.  If I execute this from a terminal under my own username, it echoes back 'dave' and pianobar still pauses.

The fifo I created `/home/dave/.config/pianobar/piano` was `chmod`ded to 777.  What gives?  Is this a permissions issue somehow?  Is PHP not allowing me to do anything useful with the `system()` command?

Answer (score 0):

Check folder permissions:

```
stat --format '%a' /home/dave/.config/pianobar/piano
```

Set folder permissions for all files inside of folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/dave/.config/pianobar/piano
```

Try, should work.

Comment: No dice. Just tried. Still works fine executing the script from a terminal, but not when I execute from Apache.

Comment: Do you have tested with "exec()"? I have tested on my local Xampp server system("stat --format '%a' /opt/lampp/htdocs")."\n";
system('whoami'); and it works fine. I think it's a permission problem.